# Syntax help needed with query criteria

Tags: grails

I have this class:

```
class IndividualRecord {
     String citizenship
     static namedQueries = {
        foreignIndividuals {
            not {ilike('citizenship', 'US')}
            fileImportService.matchCountry(citizenship) //returns true if citizenship is a valid country
        }
     }
}
```

what I am trying to do is build a named query to identify foreign citizens. So, I want all people who are not US Citizens but are from a country whose two letter country code matches the set of country codes I have in the database. This latter part is done by fileImportService.matchCountry(citizenship) returning a true which is another method I wrote.

Now, in another service called the recordSearchService, I am trying to use this named query in a method like this:

```
def individualSearch(Map params) {

    def searchResults = IndividualRecord.withCriteria {
        if (params.foreignCitizen == 'on') //This is a check box on the gsp 
            foreignIndividuals() // call to my named query
    }
}
```

and I get this error:

```
No signature of method: com.twc.fatcaone.RecordSearchService.foreignIndividuals() is applicable for argument types: () values: []. Stacktrace follows:
Message: No signature of method: com.twc.fatcaone.RecordSearchService.foreignIndividuals() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
    Line | Method
->>   20 | doCall                in com.twc.fatcaone.RecordSearchService$_$tt__individualSearch_closure2
```

I think I need help with the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this:

```
class IndividualRecord {
    String citizenship
    static namedQueries = {
        foreignIndividuals {
            not {ilike('citizenship', 'US')}
            fileImportService.matchCountry(citizenship)
        }
    }
}
```

That call to `fileImportService.matchCountry(citizenship)` is not going to affect the query in the way that you expect.  You probably want something like this:

```
class IndividualRecord {
    String citizenship
    static namedQueries = {
        foreignIndividuals {
            not {ilike('citizenship', 'US')}
            'in'('citizenship', [ /* some list of codes here */ ])
        }
    }
}
```

One way you could go about this is to accept a list of codes as an argument:

```
class IndividualRecord {
    String citizenship
    static namedQueries = {
        foreignIndividuals { List countryCodes ->
            not {ilike('citizenship', 'US')}
            'in'('citizenship', countryCodes)
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

**EDIT:**

On second read of the original question, I am not sure if the answer above is really what you want because now I think that what you are trying to do is not possible.  It looks like what you want is to have your query pass values from the database as an argument to your `fileImportService.matchCountry` method, which of course cannot happen without retrieving every non citizen record from the database first and pulling them back to the app.  You can do that of course, but depending on the amount of data you have, that may or may not be practical.  That could look something like this:

```
class IndividualRecord {
    String citizenship
    static namedQueries = {
        foreignIndividuals {
            not {
                ilike('citizenship', 'US')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could filter the results with something like this:

```
def matchingRecords = IndividualRcord.foreignIndividuals.list().findAll {
    fileImportService.matchCountry(it.citizenship)
}
```

I am not sure if that is going to be helpful or not, but I hope it helps clarify the possiblities.

Comment: Thanks, this approach makes sense but I'm having trouble with how to mix that into a criteria builder. This attempt:                            `def searchResults = IndividualRecord.withCriteria {
      eq("batchID", params.selectedBatch.id)
      if (params.USCitizen == 'on')
       ilike('citizenship', 'US')
      if (params.foreignCitizen == 'on')
       foreignIndividuals(validCountryCodes()).list()`} causes an error with the last line where I am trying to call the query where validCountryCodes() is a method that returns a list of two letter country codes.

Comment: If you want to mix arbitrary criteria code with a call to a named query, you should do it the other way around.  See the section near the bottom of http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html under "Named criteria support additional criteria being supplied at invocation time in the form of a criteria closure".

Comment: The code posed in that comment wanders a good bit from the original question.  If you can't make it work, instead of modifying the original question here, which is going to confuse future readers, post a new question about the new approach and show how you are defining the new named query and how you are trying to invoke it.  Glad I can help.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested ,but as per the grails doc, you can try the below code snippet:

```
if (params.foreignCitizen == 'on')
 def foreigIndiviList = IndividualRecord.foreignIndividuals.list()
```

Using Withcriteria am just trying to call named queries.